# How to properly add script and style to popup JavaScript window

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript file which generates a popup window. I'm trying to add style and script files so that window will be relatively self sufficient.

```
  newWindow = window.open('', newWindow, windowFeatures);
  newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '';
  var styleElement = newWindow.document.createElement("link");
  styleElement.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
  styleElement.setAttribute("type","text/css");
  styleElement.setAttribute("href","popupreport.css");
  newWindow.document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

  var header = newWindow.document.createElement("H2");
  header.innerHTML = "Label 2";
  newWindow.document.body.appendChild(header);
```

This isn't working. I can see "Label 2", but the style isn't being applied. I tried writing directly to the document like this:

```
  newWindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='popupreport.css'>");
  newWindow.document.write("<script src='test.js'></script>");

  var header = newWindow.document.createElement("H2");
  header.innerHTML = "Label 2";
  newWindow.document.body.appendChild(header);
```

This appears to get the style, but now the body in the last line generates an error. Apparently the document can only have one element at at time and the write function overwrites the body. I tried one more version which would add things to the head, but not the body. It doesn't use write, just appends.

```
  temp.innerHTML = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='popupreport.css'>"
               + "<script src='test.js'></script>";
  newWindow.document.head.appendChild(temp);

  var header = newWindow.document.createElement("H2");
  header.innerHTML = "Label 2";
  newWindow.document.body.appendChild(header);
```

I get my Label 2 again, but no style anymore.

I would prefer to use body.append statments to dynamically add content to the page, but I want that style and script page.

What is going one and how can I fix both problems?

--------UPDATE---------
I am adding two files which represent a proposed answer

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function popup() {
        var windowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,left=100,top=100";
        newWindow = window.open('', '', windowFeatures);
        newWindow.document.head.innerHTML = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='popupreport.css'>";

        var header = newWindow.document.createElement("H2");
        header.innerHTML = "Label 2";
        newWindow.document.body.appendChild(header);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="popup()">Popup</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popupreport.css

```
h2 {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `script` and `style` element in `head` of new window and add other html content in body.

```
const newWindow = window.open('','newWindow');
newWindow.document.head.innerHTML = `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popupreport.css"><script src="test.js"></script>`;
const header = newWindow.document.createElement("H2");
header.innerHTML = "Label 2";
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(header);
```

Comment: I tried that out, but it hasn't had the desired effect. The label is still black instead of red. I have added code following your solution to the end of the question.

Comment: I have put a minimal example at https://bsdillon.github.io/homeschool/temp.html

Comment: It is because your style file is not loading. Make sure that the file you have mentioned exist.

Comment: The styel file is right there. https://bsdillon.github.io/homeschool/popupreport.css

Comment: Can you try giving the absolute path instead of relative path of style file? Ex - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bsdillon.github.io/homeschool/popupreport.css">`